# Как добавить элементы в ToolBar если он не прописан в activity_main.xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, activity, android-toolbar

В Android Studio создаем Empty Activity. Как добавить допустим кнопку на этот стандартный тулбар?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нет в разметке, но по теме есть, нужно брать системный бар:

```
getSupportActionBar()
```

Дальше после этого нужно в папке `res/menu` (если нет создайте) добавить менюшку, например main_menu.xml (файл взял например):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <menu
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="@string/action_settings"
            app:showAsAction="never" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_search"
            android:orderInCategory="200"
            android:title="Search"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>                
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_user"
            android:orderInCategory="300"
            android:title="User"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_user"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />        
    </menu>
```

дальше идем в активность и прикрепляем к вашему тулбару созданное меню и нажимаем `ctrl+o` и ищем методы которые ниже:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
int id = item.getItemId();

if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
   return true;
}

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

и делаем выбор элементов которые вы сделали в ресурсах. Вот есть [туториал](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/actionbar.php) по данному вопросу.

### UPDATE

После создания `empty activity` вам нужно будет проверить нету ли в теме тулбара, потому что тогда после перетаскивания их будет два. Если я правильно понял, то под перетаскиванием вы подразумеваете использование `Palette` и виджетов в ней. После того как вы перетащили тулбар в редакторе дизайна, у вас будет что-то типа такого:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"  
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
      android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

дальше вы можете работать с ним из под активности:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

ну и разумеется использовать приведенные выше методы для работы с менюшкой из ресурсов.

Comment: Вы можете прислать еще и случай когда мы создали Empty Activity и перетащили на него ToolBar? Я смотрел туториалы как сделать с существующим но там не Empty Activity. А если где-то и найдется с empty прошу не кидать ссылки, а объяснить)

Comment: @edcft, обновил ответ

Comment: Я создал папку menu там создал xml, `Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` прописал это, но в setSupportActionbar красным подчеркивается toolbar(который в скобках). Как исправить?

Comment: уберите `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` и если вам нужно в любом месте активности использовать тулбар, то сделайте глобальную переменную и к ней обращайтесь

Comment: Я так и не понял как создать слушатель клика для search, users и для элементов трех точек которые находятся справа. Помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: в этом методе `onOptionsItemSelected` как показано в ответе, вы перед строкой `return true;` в этом куске `if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
   return true;
}` делаете то что вам нужно при клике на элемент, сколько у вас элементов в меню? если у вас появилось три точки значит их слишком много чтобы отобразить все, поэтому они перемещены в это подменю

Comment: Вот мой MainActivity.java, но при клике на search ничего не происходит, а должна закрыться программа, что я делаю не так? [ссылка](https://docs.google.com/document/d/132SoB9F1l4vqzDVJbMzNfOVd0o2j_YSrIQ-7-lBBqC4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109423/discussion-between-andrew-and-edcft).